# "java.net.UnknownHostException: abcd.efgh.co.uk" while testing the web application on remote server

Tags: jmeter

I am getting the following exception while using Jmeter to test application running on another remote server.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: abcd.efgh.co.uk
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1054)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1043)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The same script is running successfully for the web application running on the localhost.

Am I missing any configuration that need to be done for testing the applications running on remote servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually able to establish a connection to this host from the remote server? You know, can you telnet to it? (Type 'telnet abcd.efgh.co.uk 80' & 'telnet abcd.efgh.co.uk 443').

Comment: Added Proxy Server Name in HTTP Request Defaults screen to resolve the issue.  Thank You very much Oliver.

Comment: Hemanth, Facing similar issue still, can you show the settings of Http Request Default & Http Proxy Server in jmeter and Proxy server settings in Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following screenshot to set the proxy settings in the Jmeter. [image]

Comment: According to jmeter user manual, there are several ways to set up proxy. I just find some useful info under "
2.4.2 Using a HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" section of this page - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html